# Filter pandas df by other pandas df range of variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df:

| x |
| --- |
| 15 |
| 12 |
| 25 |
| 16 |
| 41 |

I want to filter it by second df frame that looks like

| Variable Name | Variable Min | Variable Max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 15 | 20 |

if anyone could help with a function for this that would be great. There are more variables in both DF but this is template

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["x"], "min": [2], "max": [4]})
df2.set_index("col", inplace=True)
df[df.loc[:,"x"].between(df2.loc["x", "min"], df2.loc["x", "max"])
```

Something like this could work? I don't use Pandas much so there may be better patterns.

Comment: Thank you for the help! That works but how would I get it to work for multiple different variables, say for x, y, z. without writing it out specifically everytime. Trying to get function to work

To clarify say there are 15 variables in df and and 15 min max ranges in df2

Answer (score 0):

I have created an artificial example with two variables `x,y`, but there could be as many variables as you might want.

The data with the actual values are stored in a DataFrame called `df` and the data with the ranges for each variable are stored in a DataFrame called `ranges_df`.

```
from typing import List

import pandas as pd

def create_features_mask(
    df: pd.DataFrame, ranges_df: pd.DataFrame, features: List
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    features_mask = pd.Series()

    for feature in features:
        feature_range = ranges_df[ranges_df["Variable Name"] == feature]

        lower = feature_range["Variable Min"].squeeze()
        upper = feature_range["Variable Max"].squeeze()

        feature_mask = df[feature].between(lower, upper)

        features_mask = pd.concat([features_mask, feature_mask], axis=1)

    return features_mask
```

Let's say we have the following dataframes:

```
    x   y
0   10  100
1   20  200
2   30  300
3   40  400
4   50  500
```

and the `ranges_df` DataFrame:

```
    Variable Name   Variable Min    Variable Max
0   x               10              30
1   y               200             300
```

We can create the features_mask variable as:

`features_mask = create_features_mask(df, ranges_df, ["x", "y"])`

and filtering the actual dataframe

`df_masked = df[features_mask]` yields:

```
    x       y
0   10.0    NaN
1   20.0    200.0
2   30.0    300.0
3   NaN     NaN
4   NaN     NaN
```

Now, you can use any way you want to filter the masked dataframe (if you want to do so), e.g.

`df_masked.dropna(how="all", axis=0)` which yields:

```
    x       y
0   10.0    NaN
1   20.0    200.0
2   30.0    300.0
```

`df_masked.dropna(how="any", axis=0)`, which yields:

```
    x       y
1   20.0    200.0
2   30.0    300.0
```